# Why does apps like Duo, whatsapp, skype has entries in the RawContact table of native Contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am using ContactContracts API to fetch the entries in RawContacts table

```
private void fetchRawContactEntries() {
        String [] mProjectionColumns = new String [] {
            RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
        };

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, mProjectionColumns, null, null,
                RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " ASC");
        if(c != null) {
            while(c.moveToNext()) {
                long contactId = c.getLong(0);
                String accountName = c.getString(1);
                String accountType = c.getString(2);
                String displayName = c.getString(3);

                Log.d("Logs", contactId +  ", accountName:" + accountName + ", Display Name : " + displayName);
            }
        }
    }
```

I observe that each contact has multiple entries in the raw_contacts table. (Gmail, Duo etc)

```
2019-05-28 19:21:15.483 5458-5458/com.example.kartikaysingh.cs D/Logs: 2227, accountName:kartikayemail@gmail.com, Display Name : Abhay Y
2019-05-28 19:21:15.483 5458-5458/com.example.kartikaysingh.cs D/Logs: 2227, accountName:WhatsApp, Display Name : Abhay Y
2019-05-28 19:21:15.483 5458-5458/com.example.kartikaysingh.cs D/Logs: 2227, accountName:Duo, Display Name : Abhay Y
2019-05-28 19:21:15.483 5458-5458/com.example.kartikaysingh.cs D/Logs: 2227, accountName:Duo, Display Name : Abhay Y
2019-05-28 19:21:15.483 5458-5458/com.example.kartikaysingh.cs D/Logs: 2140, accountName:kartik@gmail.com, Display Name : Abhayuday
2019-05-28 19:21:15.483 5458-5458/com.example.kartikaysingh.cs D/Logs: 2140, accountName:WhatsApp, Display Name : Abhayuday
2019-05-28 19:21:15.484 5458-5458/com.example.kartikaysingh.cs D/Logs: 2140, accountName:Duo, Display Name : Abhayuday
2019-05-28 19:21:15.484 5458-5458/com.example.kartikaysingh.cs D/Logs: 2140, accountName:Duo, Display Name : Abhayuday
```

Infact `Duo` make two different entries in the RawContact table. How does `native contact` app differentiate between these entries.
I know they show the entries of the **Contacts table** but when **modifying** a data which raw_contact_id they choose out of `Duo or Whatsapp or gmail`.
From where they get these original **raw_contact_id** ?

**Here are the things i already know :**

1. Contact Id of the duplicate entries will be **same** irrespective of the sources which is handled by the Contact Provider. Check this one out [ContactsAggregator](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_providers_contactsprovider/blob/master/src/com/android/providers/contacts/aggregation/ContactAggregator2.java)
2. Contact table has a column `name_raw_contact_id` which give the corresponding _ID  of the RawContacts table ( However i am not sure if this can be considered as the primary entry for the contact in RawContacts table).

**Given below the list of things i want to know:**

1. We can get the unique contacts from the `ContactsContract.Contact` table but in order to modify/delete  the data values (like phone, email etc) using Contact provider which raw_contact_id we can pick ? or can i go and modify directly in the `ContactContract.Data` table.
2. How do whatsapp detect the addition/modification of the contact. As far as i know Contact Provider doesn't provide the `_ID` for new contact addition. Do they refresh their contacts list after every app launch or at equal time intervals ?
3. How to get the original source for a contact (possibly gmail/native in my case) and leave out the copies created by app like Duo, skype, whatsapp using contact provider.

It would be great if anyone help me understand this. Feel free to recommend any other channel where i can ask for these questions

Answer (score 2):

The projection is indeed incorrect.

The Contacts DB is organized in three main tables:

1. `Contacts` - each entry represents one contact, and groups together one or more `RawContacts`
2. `RawContacts` - each entry represents data about a contact that was synced in by some `SyncAdapter` (e.g. Whatsapp, Google, Facebook, Viber), this groups multiple Data entries
3. `Data` - The actual data about a contact, emails, phones, etc. each line is a single piece of data that belongs to a single `RawContact`

Every app on Google Play with sufficient permissions can add a new Contact or a new RawContact and aggregate it into an existing contact, just like Whatsapp / Duo, this allows each app to store information about a specific contact, like it's Whatsapp ID, or any other info that will be useful for the app.

You have a wrong assumption that there is a single "main" RawContact that is the important one, and the others are attached to it.
Instead, the list of RawContacts that represent a single contact can contain multiple Google RawContacts with equal importance, or no Google RawContacts at all, there is one distinction that can help you select a RawContact for editing, that is whether or not the RawContacts created by the app are read-only or writeable.

Here's code to iterate over all accounts on the device, and see which are read-only and which are modifiable (`supportsUploading`):

```
final SyncAdapterType[] syncs = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
for (SyncAdapterType sync : syncs) {
    Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter: " + sync.accountType);
    if (ContactsContract.AUTHORITY.equals(sync.authority)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter that supports contacts: " + sync.accountType);
        if (sync.supportsUploading()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter that supports contacts and is not read-only: " + sync.accountType);
            // we'll now get a list of all accounts under that accountType:
            Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType(sync.accountType);
            for (Account account : accounts) {
               Log.d(TAG, account.type + " / " + account.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Explore the other good stuff in [`SyncAdapterType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SyncAdapterType.html) like `isUserVisible` that you might help you as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @marmor.
My only question is when i query Data table. i can see entries of same phone number by google, duo, whatsapp with same mimetype. But in contact application we see only one contact not three. How does contact application different if the data in Data table is provided by some sync adapter like Duo, whatsapp and not show those data (which might result in copies of the data) in the native app.

Comment: can we solve this after fetching all the sync adapter ? 
Solution is to not read/modify the read only account types? If so, then how does it pick the phone contacts and SIM contacts i think they are not registered as syncAdapterTypes

Comment: you can go over the accounts on the device using the loop in my answer to get a list of accounts you can and should modify, then when your app needs to edit a contact, you need to pick one of the `RawContacts` that belong to an account on that list, you can use `RawContact.ACCOUNT_TYPE` to figure out to which account does a raw-contact belong to

Comment: Dude what if i set supportUploading to false. still uploads the local data to server ? i mean how setting it to true/false affect the syncadapter ?

Comment: you can't set it to false, it's just the app communicating how its syncadapter is set to work, it's like an FYI

Comment: we can still set supportUploading to false in my sync adapter xml still can upload the data to server. Is my understanding right ?

Comment: @alphaguy I'm having the same issue in differentiating the `MIMETYPE`s of apps like WhatsApp, Duo. When I queried `ContactsContract.Data` table, I found `Message xxx`, `Video call xxx` `Voice call xxx` of WhatsApp for a contact in `DATA3` column. However, for Duo I found the same in `DATA5` column. How do we get which column that holds such values? Columns `DATA1..DATA4` filled with some other data for Duo and `DATA1..DATA2` are filled with something else for WhatsApp.